# phpMyAdmin sql panel is interpting a string as column

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

I'm trying to follow a mysql tutorial from The New Boston on youtube. However, I have a problem with the sql panel in phpmyadmin interprets text in quotes as columns. In my version of phpMyadmin,  (Server version: 5.1.55,Protocol version: 10,MySQL client version: 5.1.55)I did not see a way to turn this off.
Please see images from this link [http://leobee.com/android/push/phpmyadminerrors.html](http://www.leobee.com/android/push/phpmyadminerrors.html)

In phpMyAdmin columns can have quotes or be without quotes in sql queries:
See Image 1 and Image 2

The error 1054 unknown column for the name of a city (which is a string):
See Image 3

I get an error 1064 error in syntax when I escape the string:
See Image 4

I also get and error when the quotes are removed from around the string for the city (which is correct).

The error log says it's a syntax error, but it is not. How do I get the application to use quotes only for strings?

Comment: In image 3 you are using back-ticks, not single quotes.  In image 4, you are trying to escape a quote.  Try: `SELECT city FROM customers WHERE city='Raleigh'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhpMyAdmin, like MySQL uses both quotes and back-ticks.  Both are different and shouldn't be used interchangeably.

Back-ticks are used for columns or tables:

```
SELECT * FROM `customers`
-OR-
SELECT `city` FROM `customers`
```

Using a single quote will throw an error:

```
SELECT * FROM 'customers'
-OR-
SELECT 'city' FROM 'customers'
```

Single quotes should be used for strings.  Any additional quotes inside should be properly escaped:

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE `city`='Raleigh'
-OR-
SELECT city FROM customers WHERE city='Lee\'s Summit'
```

Improperly escaping quotes will throw an error:

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE `city`=\'Raleigh\'
-OR-
SELECT city FROM customers WHERE city='Lee's Summit'
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I've tested out the suggestions above and I am still having problems with this issue. Please see this screencast:[link](http://screencast.com/t/2IKL0pHWj4) @Tim Withers

Comment: That is very odd.  I don't have any of those issues.  It looks like it is auto-escaping quotes.  I don't know if that is PhpMyAdmin or PHP/Apache that is doing that.  Sorry.